# ExternalAccessory and NSUserDefaults strange issue

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, nsuserdefaults

I am working with `ExternalAccessory` FW and able to pass data to the peripheral device.

I am facing a strange situation, when trying to save some value to `NSUserDefaults` I'm getting this (looks like) unrelated error:

```
UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols = com.xxxxx.yyy.zz
2013-07-24 17:01:39.181 myApp[791:907] ERROR - opening session failed
2013-07-24 17:01:39.182 myApp[791:907] ERROR - /SourceCache/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-213.3/EASession.m:-[EASession dealloc] - 137 unable to close session for _accessory=0x2088cdb0 and sessionID=65536
```

And connection with peripheral is dead.

The code that writes to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSInteger transactionId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kTransactionId];
transactionId = transactionId % NSIntegerMax + 1;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:transactionId forKey:kTransactionId];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

If I comment out `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:transactionId forKey:kTransactionId];` everything works just fine...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults works in the main thread. Perhaps you want to use something different, maybe an NSMutableDictionary that you then serialize to disk.